# Ubuntu Wiki BuildYourOwnKernel Questions

Tags: kernel, 20.04, raspberrypi, arm64

I'm trying to build a new Ubuntu 20.04 Arm64 kernel for the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B using the Ubuntu Wiki [BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) instructions and there is something that is puzzling me.

If I add "+test" to the "debian.master/changelog" revision number, as per the instructions, this doesn't get picked up and the kernel is built without the "+test".

I have followed the instructions to the letter.

Any suggestions how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing like `unman`. Did you mistype the command? Also, please [edit] your question and narrow down it's scope. Please try to ask one question at a time. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Kulfy. I've fixed the typo in my question, it should have been "uname". My questions all relate to the same Ubuntu Wiki document. Is it not OK to have my queries in the same question? Please let me know if not, happy to amend.

Comment: `build-up`? Is that supposed to be `build-dep`? Also, none of these three questions have any particular dependency on the others. They're independent and could be (and probably should be) asked separately. You just happen to have a common context for them.

Comment: Indeed, a typo, it should be `build-dep`. And I have split the question up. Thanks.

Comment: do not remove the reference link again. I was not aware that a `+` could be used in custom names. try `-`.

Answer (score 1):

The `linux-raspi-5.4.0` source directory has two directories, `debian.master` and `debian.raspi`. The `BuildYourOwnKernel` instructions suggest adding `+test` to the version number in `debian.master/changelog`. This doesn't work. However, adding `+test` to the version number in `debian.raspi/changelog` does. My kernel works as required and `uname -a` displays `5.4.0-1013-raspi #13+test`.

Many thanks for all the comments.